# Arranging odd and even numbers in a vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have this problem: Given a vector with n numbers, sort the numbers so that the even ones will be on odd positions and the odd numbers will be on even positions. E.g. If I have  the vector 2 6 7 8 9 3 5 1, the output should be 2 7 6 9 8 3 5 1 .  The count should start from 1. So on position 1 which is actually index 0 should be an even number, on position 2 which is actually index 1 should be an odd number and so on. Now this is easy if the odd and even numbers are the same, let's say 4 even number and 4 odd numbers in the vector, but what if the number of odd numbers differs from the number of even numbers like in the above example? How do I solve that. I attached the code with one of the tries I did, but it doesn't work. Can I get some help please. I ask you to keep it simple that means only with vectors and such. No weird methods or anything cause I'm a beginner and I only know the basics. Thanks in advance!
I have to mention that n initial is globally declared and is the number of vector elements and v_initial is the initial vector with the elements that need to be rearranged.

The task says to add the remaining numbers to the end of the vector. Like if there are 3 odd and 5 even numbers, The 2 extra even numbers should be thrown at the end of the vector

```
void vector_pozitii_pare_impare(int v_initial[])
{
    int v_pozitie[50],c1=0,c2=1;
    for (i = 0; i < n_initial; i++)
    {
        if (v_initial[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            bool isTrue = 1;
            for (int k = i + 1; k < n_initial; k++)
            {
                if (v_initial[k] % 2 != 0)
                    isTrue = 0;
            }
            if (isTrue)
            {
                v_pozitie[c1] = v_initial[i];
                c1++;
            }
            else
            {
                v_pozitie[c1] = v_initial[i];
                c1 += 2;
            }
            
            
        }
        else
        {
            bool isTrue = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n_initial; j++)
            {
                if (v_initial[j] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    isTrue = 0;
                }

                if (isTrue)
                {
                    v_pozitie[c2] = v_initial[i];
                    c2++;
                }
                else
                {
                    v_pozitie[c2] = v_initial[i];
                    c2 += 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *I attached the code with one of the tries I did, but it doesn't work* -- Now is a good time to learn how to use the piece of software that comes with your compiler called the *debugger*.  It allows you to single-step through your code, watch variables, etc.

Comment: If you start by changing your language to calling the first element 0, e.g. an even position, then you can just say even values need to be on even positions and vice versa. Not sure if that's leading to some confusion. You also give an example of what the output *should* be. Is this the only possible solution or is this one of many solutions? What happens if there is not an even distribution of even/odd numbers? I know you're asking what to do in that case, but I'm asking YOU what YOU want to happen in that case.

Comment: _", but what if the number of odd numbers differs from the number of even numbers like in the above example?"_ - If the task does not clarify this case (or gives certain restrictions, such that this case can never occurr) there is nothing we can do about it. Maybe insert 0's? Maybe throw an error? The task probably clarifies it.

Comment: The task says to add the remaining numbers to the end of the vector. Like if there are 3 odd and 5 even numbers, The 2 extra even numbers should be thrown at the end of the vector

Comment: I suggest you draw this on paper first before writing any code.  It seems you jumped straight into writing code without too much of a plan.

Comment: "but it doesn't work" tell us what doesn't work about it. Off the top of my head I see that you're populating a local array with values, but outside of this function that array doesn't exist. Accessing that memory is dangerous. If possible, use `std::vector<int>` (digging in your heels and not using `std::vector` in modern C++ is like building a modern car but not using fuel injection or power steering)

Comment: @Tyby2017 -- You don't have to be fancy if you realize you can solve this problem using 3 different index values.  The first index indicates where the current even number is in the original array, the second index indicates where the current odd number is in the original array, and a third index points to the current position in the output array where a value will be written.  Then it's a matter of controlling all of those indices correctly (making sure they start out correctly, incrementing them when needed, knowing when it's time to stop processing and return the new array, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a perfect solution and it just popped out right off my mind without being tested or verified, but it's just to give you an *idea*.

(Let `A,B,C,D` be odd numbers and `0,1,2` even numbers correspondingly)

Given:

`A 0 B C D 1 2` (random ordered list of odd/even numbers)

Wanted:

`A 0 B 1 C 2 D` (input sequence altered to match the wanted odd/even criteria)

Next, we invent the steps required to get from given to wanted:

```
// look at 'A' -> match, next
// Result: A 0 B C D 1 2  

// look at '0' -> match, next
// Result: A 0 B C D 1 2

// look at 'B' -> match, next
// Result: A 0 B C D 1 2

// look at 'C' -> mismatch, remember index and find first match starting from index+1
// Result: A 0 B C D ->1<- 2 

// now swap the numbers found at the remembered index and the found one.
// Result: A 0 B 1 D C 2 

// continue until the whole list has been consumed.
```

As I said, this algorithm may not be perfect, but my intention is to give you an example on how to solve these kinds of problems. It's not good to always think in code first, especially not with a problem like this. So you should first think about where you start, what you want to achieve and then carefully think of *how* to get there step by step.

I feel I have to mention that I did not provide an example in real code, because once you got the idea, the execution should be pretty much straight forward.

Oh, and just a small remark: Almost *nothing* about your code is C++.

Comment: What's A, B, C, and D? Hexadecimal? A and C are even. B and D are odd. Your output sequence goes `even even odd odd odd even even` if that's the case.

Comment: @JohnFilleau `0, 1, 2` are values of one kind, `A, B, C, D` are values of another kind

Comment: looking at the example, I think he wants a stable result.

Comment: And you are complaining about "Almost nothing about your code is C++."  Where is your code in the first place? And what is this ABC stuff?

Comment: @ArminMontigny no, I did not complain about it, its not a judgement in any way, I just wanted to point that out because I think this might be important for the enquirer. I was just giving an idea about the algorithm, purposely in no specific language, because I was under the impression that this would be what the actual question was about.

Comment: Also, yes, sorry, of course `A,B,C,D` meant to be odd and `0,1,2` even values or the other way. Sorry for the confusion, I will add this information to the answer.

Comment: @fdan You are correct, this algorithm is not stable, but I by myself couldn't spot this requirement in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, that is not very efficient would be to split the vector into 2 vectors, that contain even and uneven numbers and then always take one from the even, one from the uneven and then the remainder, from the one that is not completely entered.

some c++ (that actually uses vectors, but you can use an array the same way, but need to change the pointer arithmetic)
I did not test it, but the principle should be clear; it is not very efficient though

EDIT: The answer below by @AAAAAAAAARGH outlines a better algorithmic idea, that is inplace and more efficient.

```
void change_vector_even_uneven(std::vector<unsigned>& in_vec){
      std::vector<unsigned> even;
      std::vector<unsigned> uneven;
  
      for (auto it = in_vec.begin(); it != in_vec.end(); it++){
          if ((*it) % 2 == 0)) even.push_back(*it);
          else uneven.push_back(*it);
      }
      
      auto even_it = even.begin();
      auto uneven_it = uneven.begin();
      for (auto it = in_vec.begin(); it != in_vec.end(); it++){
          if (even_it == even.end()){
              (*it) = (*uneven_it);
              uneven_it++;
              continue; 
          }   
          if (uneven_it == uneven.end()){
              (*it) = (*even_it);
              even_it++;
              continue;
          }   
          if ((it - in_vec.begin()) % 2 == 0){
              (*it) = (*even_it);
              even_it++;
          }
          else{
              (*it) = (*uneven_it);
              uneven_it++;
          }   
      }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions is simple. We sort the even and odd values into a data structure. In a loop, we iterate over all source values. If they are even (val & 2 == 0) we add them at the end of a `std::deque` for evens and if odd, we add them to a `std::deque` for odds.

Later, we we will extract the the values from the front of the `std::deque`.

So, we have a first in first out principle.
The `std::deque` is optimized for such purposes.

Later, we make a loop with an alternating branch in it. We, alternatively extract data from the even queue and then from the odd queue. If a queue is empty, we do not extract data.

We do not need an additional `std::vector` and can reuse the old one.

With that, we do not need to take care for the same number of evens and odds. It will of course always work.

Please see below one of millions of possible solutions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

int main() {

    std::vector testData{ 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 1 };

    // Show initial data
    std::cout << "\nInitial data: ";
    for (const int i : testData) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    // We will use a deques to store odd and even numbers
    // With that we can efficiently push back and pop front
    std::deque<int> evenNumbers{};
    std::deque<int> oddNumbers{};

    // Sort the original data into the specific container
    for (const int number : testData)
        if (number % 2 == 0) 
            evenNumbers.push_back(number);
        else 
            oddNumbers.push_back(number);

    // Take alternating the data from the even and the odd values
    bool takeEven{ true };
    for (size_t i{}; !evenNumbers.empty() && !oddNumbers.empty(); ) {

        if (takeEven) {  // Take even numbers
            if (not evenNumbers.empty()) {          // As long as there are even values
                testData[i] = evenNumbers.front();  // Get the value from the front
                evenNumbers.pop_front();            // Remove first value
                ++i;
            }
        } 
        else { // Now we take odd numbers
            if (not oddNumbers.empty()) {           // As long as there are odd values
                testData[i] = oddNumbers.front();   // Get the value from the front
                oddNumbers.pop_front();             // Remove first value
                ++i;
            }
        }
        // Next take the other container
        takeEven = not takeEven;
    }

    // Show result
    std::cout << "\nResult:       ";
    for (const int i : testData) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another solution (using STL), in case you want a *stable* result (that is, the order of your values is preserved).

```
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <vector>

  auto ints = std::vector<int>{ 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 1 };

  // split list to even/odd sections -> [2, 6, 8, 7, 9, 3, 5, 1]
  const auto it = std::stable_partition(
    ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](auto value) { return value % 2 == 0; });

  auto results = std::vector<int>{};
  results.reserve(ints.size());

  // merge both parts with equal size
  auto a = ints.begin(), b = it;
  while (a != it && b != ints.end()) {
    results.push_back(*a++);
    results.push_back(*b++);
  }

  // copy remaining values to end of list
  std::copy(a, it, std::back_inserter(results));
  std::copy(b, ints.end(), std::back_inserter(results));
```

The result ist `[2, 7, 6, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1]`. The complexity is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer, like some of the others, divides the data and then reassembles the result. The standard library [`std::partition_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy) is used to separate the even and odd numbers into two containers. Then the `interleave` function assembles the result by alternately copying from two input ranges.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename InIt1, typename InIt2, typename OutIt>
OutIt interleave(InIt1 first1, InIt1 last1, InIt2 first2, InIt2 last2, OutIt dest)
{
    for (;;) {
        if (first1 == last1) {
            return std::copy(first2, last2, dest);
        }
        *dest++ = *first1++;

        if (first2 == last2) {
            return std::copy(first1, last1, dest);
        }
        *dest++ = *first2++;
    }
}

void reorder_even_odd(std::vector<int> &data)
{
    auto is_even = [](int value) { return (value & 1) == 0; };

    // split
    std::vector<int> even, odd;
    std::partition_copy(begin(data), end(data), back_inserter(even), back_inserter(odd), is_even);

    // merge
    interleave(begin(even), end(even), begin(odd), end(odd), begin(data));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data{ 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 1 };

    reorder_even_odd(data);

    for (int value : data) {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sfPFSF)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I am using vectors and STL.
No need to be a great mathematician to understand v_pozitie will start with pairs of odd and even and terminate with the integers not in the initial pairs.
I am then updating three iterators in v_positie (no need of temporary containers to calculate the result) : even, odd and end,(avoiding push_back) and would code this way :

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void vector_pozitii_pare_impare(std::vector<int>& v_initial, std::vector<int>& v_pozitie) {

  int nodd (0), neven (0);
  std::for_each (v_initial.begin (), v_initial.end (), [&nodd] (const int& n) {
    nodd += n%2;
  });
  neven = v_initial.size () - nodd;

  int npair (neven < nodd ?neven:nodd); 
  npair *=2;
  std::vector<int>::iterator iend (&v_pozitie [npair]), ieven (v_pozitie.begin ()), iodd (&v_pozitie [1]);

  std::for_each (v_initial.begin (), v_initial.end (), [&iend, &ieven, &iodd, &npair] (const int& s) {
    if (npair) {
      switch (s%2) {
      case 0 :
        *ieven++ = s;
        ++ieven;
        break;
      case 1 :
        *iodd++ = s;
        ++iodd;
        break;
      }
      --npair;
    }
    else *iend++ = s;
  });
}

int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  const int N = 8;
  int tab [N] = {2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 5, 1};
  std::vector<int> v_initial (tab, (int*)&tab [N]);
  std::cout << "\tv_initial == ";
  std::for_each (v_initial.begin (), v_initial.end (), [] (const int& s) {std::cout << s << "  ";});
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::vector<int> v_pozitie (v_initial.size (), -1);
  vector_pozitii_pare_impare (v_initial, v_pozitie);
  
  std::cout << "\tv_pozitie == ";
  std::for_each (v_pozitie.begin (), v_pozitie.end (), [] (const int& s) {std::cout << s << "  ";});
  std::cout << std::endl;  
}
```